# Restore user data, settings and apps from hard-drive copy

Tags: mac, backup, restore, install

Here's the situation:

1. My GF's MacBook Pro broke, OS would not start at all
2. I inserted Knoppix Live CD, booted and just copied all of the files from her HD to folder on  external HD
3. I've reinstalled OS on MacBook pro

My questions is: how can I easily restore all of her settings from HD to new OS installation and user account? Will simple copying files do the job? And what kind of software you recommend for backups?

I'm coming from *NIX / PC background, and new to Mac OS X, so wanted make sure before proceeding.

Answer (score 1):

When you say settings what do you mean?

What current version of MAC os will you be restoring too?

Migration Assistant will allow you to restore from an external drive, if the drive has been formatted in the OS X Journaled format with the proper GUID.